# Why/How/When to use the __using__(which) macro in Phoenix Controller/View/etc?

Tags: macros, phoenix-framework, elixir

## Context

Inside every Phoenix (Elixir Web Framework) App, at the bottom of the `/lib/{yourapp}_web.ex` file 
e.g: [`/lib/chat_web.ex`](https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-chat-example/blob/b57cc174d7f1c9aac22947f23170b29d4c303776/lib/chat_web.ex#L61-L66)
there is a `__using__/1` macro  defined as:

```
@doc """
When used, dispatch to the appropriate controller/view/etc.
"""
defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
  apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
end
```

## **Question**: what is the `__using__/1` macro used *for*?

If you can, share (*or link to*) a *usage example* which will help demonstrate it in a *real world* context.

Where does the `apply` function come from given that it's not "imported" in the `/lib/{yourapp}_web.ex` file and what is the *effect* of the "apply" ?

> We have tried googling and reading several docs, tutorials, blog posts etc. on Macros. e.g:

- https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html
- https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/metaprogramming/
- https://hackernoon.com/understanding-elixir-macros-3464e141434c
- https://medium.com/@Mike_Andr/understanding-elixirs-macros-by-phoenix-example-e99827a60987

But still no closer to *understanding* the why/when/how we would use `__using__/1` macro ... :-(

If we attempt to comment out or delete it from `lib/chat_web.ex` the app does not compile even though it is not *invoked* from with `chat_web.ex` ... and `excoveralls` (test coverage reporting) reports that it's *not* being executed.

I find this confusing / non-beginner-friendly and searching the Phoenix guide (docs) is not particularly insightful e.g:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/29536f3b86154ab64647643a3eeeb263e33834cd/guides/controllers.md
[image]

### Further context:

In the Phoenix Chat Example/Tutorial: https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-chat-example

 We are tracking test coverage as a *learning* exercise ... 
There is only ***one*** line of code that is *not* being covered by Tests:
https://codecov.io/gh/dwyl/phoenix-chat-example/src/b57cc174d7f1c9aac22947f23170b29d4c303776/lib/chat_web.ex#L65
[image]

How is it that the line is not being executed ("*covered*") when we run the tests, but if we comment *out* the line the tests *fail*?

Is this macro "*magic*" in that it is being "used" without actually being *called*? 
Any [shoshin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshin) insight *much* appreciated!

Comment: Recently I come across the same thing and i searched but couldn't find the the answer. But then I implemented it in my project and that makes sense. Let me give you example where I use it. I have test cases that have same controller written with macro. so its not suitable for me ti write similar test cases for each controller .so i used macro `__using__/1`. and include that macro in every controller test . It solves my problem of writing same code for each test controller over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: the best source is the Elixir documentation, not guides, tutorials and blog posts. Let me cite this excerpt from [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2):

> When calling:
>
> ```
> use MyModule, some: :options
> ```
>
> the `__using__/1` macro from the `MyModule` module is invoked with the second argument passed to use as its argument. Since `__using__/1` is a macro, all the usual macro rules apply, and its return value should be quoted code that is then inserted where `use/2` is called.

There are also examples there, which might clarify the concept on itself.

---

> How is it that the line is not being executed (*“covered”*) when we run the tests, but if we comment out the line the tests *fail*?

Since it’s a macro, it is *injected into the calling source code on compilation stage*. That said, when `use ThisModule` is called, the AST, returned by `__using__/1` *is being injected into the caller’s context*.

I have no idea why Coverage is so stupid to mark this line, though.

Comment: A thread about problems with coverage of macros https://github.com/parroty/excoveralls/issues/59